# CSRT algorithm not updating target

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-tracking

I am using OPENCV built-in tracker CSRT for object detection and tracking, I found it best for using but I have question here when the target gets out of frame it still have a bounding box at last position he tracked when target comes back to frame it doesn't track that. From OPENCV documentation I came to know that this is short term tracker but is there any way to know that target is now not in frame i used this command

```
success, boxes = multiTracker.update(frame)
print("Success",success)
```

to know whether it generates false but it doesn't. I have to use this algorithm for real time tracking. Moreover I am not willing for advance ML libraries like Yolo or TF, so if anyone can help with it or with some better tracker.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also working with the CSRT tracker from openCV (C++).
In my opinion, you have two options :

1) You can write an algorithm that detects if the object is still in the bounding box or not. To do so, you can take inspiration from the method implemented in trackerCSRT.cpp from tracking module of openCV (cf `CSRTImpl::estimate_new_position`). In this function, params.psr_threshold represents the threshold for which the tracked object is lost or not. So If you write a similar algorithm you will be able to determine if your object is not in your bounding box (on this algorithm, around **psr_threshold** < 0.1 you can consider it lost)

2) The second option that I recommend is to init your CSRT tracker with the function CSRT::create(const CSRT::Params &parameters) and pass a higher value to psr_threshold (for example 0.1) in order to have a tracker which is more sensitive. In this case, your tracker won't continue tracking an empty area, but will return false (target lost), which is already an improvement.
Depending on your application, you will need to implement something to find the target again in your video. Now, this is called long-term tracking.

Good luck

Comment: Can you find this for python?

Comment: According to the documentation, the python equivalent function for CSRT::create(const CSRT::Params &parameters) is  retval = cv.TrackerCSRT_create(  ) so you cannot init with your own parameters in Python. So that means the solution 2 cannot work for you. The solution would be to write an algorithm in Python to detect when the tracker has lost the target (by taking inspiration from C++ algorithms but it's pretty long and not sure you have all the functions available in Python to do so). Sorry, the implementation for the trackers in openCV Python is limited !